# Whether dom-manipulation requires a refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I have a doubt about DOM manipulation.
Whether dom-manipulation requires a refresh ? Or when did DOM manipulation requires refreshing? I see some of the sites keep loading while updating some of their parts.
Also,
How does react.js help to avoid this kind of problems while dealing with the front end development?

Comment: Ask **one** question per question, not two. There are at least two above.

Comment: How are you defining "refresh" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a doubt about DOM manipulation. Whether dom-manipulation requires a refresh ?

It depends on what you mean by "refresh." I can think of at least three possible things you could mean:

- "Refresh" like pressing F5 on a page or hitting the reload button
- "Refresh" like recalculate the positions of the elements; this is more correctly called "reflow"
- "Refresh" as in repaint the elements on the screen ("repaint")

### Reload

No, it doesn't, and in fact if you reload the page, the changes you've made to the DOM with your browser-based code will get wiped out. Here's a really simple example of DOM manipulation; no reloading is done until the end, and when it's done you can see that the changes made previously are wiped out (and then, since the code is also reloaded, we're starting from scratch, so it all starts over):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    delayedAdd(i);
}

function delayedAdd(value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // DOM manipulation
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = value;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        if (value === 4) {
            // Refresh after the last one -- wipes out what we've done
            setTimeout(() => {
                location.reload();
            }, 800);
        }
    }, value * 800);
}
```

### Reflow

Some DOM manipulations trigger reflow, yes; or more accurately, doing some things (which might be just getting, say, an element's current `clientLeft` property value) triggers reflow, and reflow *may* involve recalculating layout, which can be expensive. Code can cause reflow repeatedly, including causing the layout to be recalculated repeatedly, doing a single series of manipulations. [This list from Paul Irish](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) claims to be "What forces layout/reflow. The comprehensive list." and Paul Irish is a deeply-experienced person in this realm and well-regarded in the industry, so the list is likely to be accurate (though no one is perfect, and these things can sometimes change over time). The page also has some guidance on how to avoid reflow (or more accurately, how to avoid layout recalculation).

Here's an example of code causing unnecessary layout recalculation:

```js
const elementLefts = [];

// This loop triggers layout recalculation 10 times
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = n;
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    // Triggers layout recalcuation every time:
    elementLefts.push(span.offsetLeft);
}

console.log(elementLefts.join(", "));
```

We can get that same information after the loop and only trigger a single layout recalculation:

```js
const spans = [];

// This loop triggers layout recalculation 10 times
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = n;
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    spans.push(span);
}

// Triggers one layout recalcuation, because nothing has changed between
// times we get `offsetLeft` from an element
const elementLefts = spans.map(span => span.offsetLeft);
console.log(elementLefts.join(", "));
```

### Repaint

The browser repaints the screen all the time, typically 60 times per second (or even more if the system it's running on has a higher refresh rate) unless it's blocked by a long-running task on the UI thread (which is shared with the main JavaScript code). DOM manipulations don't cause this repaint (though changing the DOM may change what's painted, which might in turn prevent the browser reusing some painting information it had from last time).

---

> Also, How does react.js help to avoid this kind of problems while dealing with the front end development?

They can help with reflows by minimizing layout recalculations by using the knowledge of what causes recalcs and avoiding doing the things that cause them in loops, etc. That said, they're not a magic bullet, and like everything else they have cons as well as pros.

Comment: Was just about to mark this as duplicate and point to another "when does reflow happen" answer until I read this and realise that this is a really good answer to the unasked X/Y problem

Comment: @slebetman - :-) If you have a good "when does reflow happen" question, would you post a link to it in the comments (here or on the question above)? I could use the read, and people who find this probably could as well. Thanks!